# Ativação da validação Angular FormGroup

Tags: typescript, angular

Olá tenho um formulário usando formGrupo!

Quando eu clico no botão confirmar ele não realiza as validações, sem nenhuma reação nos campos...assim...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, gostaria de que quando clicasse nesse botão, ele valida os campos e retornar as mensagens de erro... assim...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código do formGroup e a chamada do botão htlm

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no botao faz assim

```
<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid" .../>
```

Comment: Então Eduardo, nessa caso meu botão vai ficar desabilitado enquanto meu Form não foi totalmente valido, porém no meu caso, desejo que ao clicar no botão ele fazer essa validação campo a campo e apresentar a mensagem de erro caso haja algum campo inválido

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/

Comment: Como sempre, muito obrigado Eduardo, seus respostas são sempre certeira...Funcionou legal...